# How to interpret traceroute results

Tags: networking, performance, monitoring

I am trying to figure out how to interpret the attached image.
First two hops are on our LAN, hops 3-5 belong to our WAN provider, while hop 6 is at our hosting provider and the hop 7 is a Windows server at that same hosting provider.

What I don't understand is how the latency on hop 7 can be lower than the latency on hop 6 or to that effect lower than the latency on hops 5 and 6. Also - the hop 6 shows significant packet loss, while hop 7 looks fine. I understand that the figures are not cumulative, but if the packet traverses all the hops, shouldn't every next hop take longer to reach than the previous one?

I read through quite a few documents, tutorials on Internet explaining the traceroute command but I still haven't found the explanation to this. I would highly appreciate a clear explanation or at least a pointer as what to read.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a theory: some core routers can have overloaded management plane - hence delayed / lost responses, yet their packet forwarding plane will perform well so traffic passing via them will not be affected.

i suggest you also test using iperf for the available bandwidth. if your end-to-end performance is acceptable then you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 2):

Traceroute is an unreliable method for measuring latency.  Remember that traceroute sends packets (ICMP in Windows, UDP in Linux) with a low TTL -  When the TTL = 0, the router sends back a "Time exceeded" ICMP message.  That's how you can identify all the hops between you and your destination.

The problem is that sending a time exceeded message is an error exception that must be handled in software (as opposed to packet forwarding, which is done in hardware).  Sending ICMP error messages is a low priority task, and on a busy router there can be significant delays or dropped messages.

If you're interested in measuring end-to-end latency, use iperf as @pQd suggests.